# Conversion from .shp to .dxf in one unified layer

Tags: shapefile, convert, 3d, arcscene, sketchup

I am trying to make a 3D .dxf out of a 2D shapefile for several hundred buildings. Doing this in one fell swoop is proving to be a roadblock.

In ArcScene, I extruded building heights for maybe two dozen city blocks in Tel Aviv then later applied the Layer 3D to Feature Class and Multipatch to Collada tools. The immediate goal was to take this swath of hundreds of cubes of various shapes and sizes representing buildings and import them into Sketchup and/or 3DS Max as a .dae for later conversion to a .dxf.

Unfortunately, the buildings can only be imported individually, one at a time, without spatial alignment to one another in both Sketchup and 3DS Max. Precision is key, so needless to say this is unacceptable. I need one cohesive layer.

The eventual goal is to import these buildings into the gaming software Unity for unwrapping and rendering with images as part of both car accident and parking spot simulations.